# Unable to run automated tests in VS 2010 on Chrome/Firefox/IE using Selenium Web driver - Shows blank page ??

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, selenium, webdriver

The browser opens and shows a blank page in all the three(Chrome/Firefox/IE). It doesn't show any error message but the test doesn't run. Unable to figure out the issue. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you are running.

Answer (score 0):

Have you doubled checked that the URL pointed to in the `open` command is correct, and a specific aspx page?

Comment: IntegrationTest.Driver = new ChromeDriver(); IntegrationTest.Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3‌​)); IntegrationTest.Driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(‌​3)); NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.ReleaseSession(); 
this is what i have... how do we specify specific page(.cshtml) to point to ?

Answer (score 0):

Show us a sample of code.

Double check that you are not only creating a new instance of each driver, but also giving a URL to go to.

Comment: IntegrationTest.Driver = new ChromeDriver();
            IntegrationTest.Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
            IntegrationTest.Driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
            NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.ReleaseSession();

Comment: this is what i have... how do we specify specific page(.cshtml) to point to ?

Comment: The issue is therefore you are not giving the web driver a place to go to. So all it will do is open a new instance of the driver and thats it. The below code is an example to go to Google.com:

`IntegrationTest.Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(http://www.google.com);`